# Почему в роуте Expressjs setTimeout срабатывает только один раз?

Tags: node.js, express

Node 14
Express 4

Надо POST обрабатывать с некоторой задержкой

Есть вот такой роут

```
router.post('/', (
    request,
    response
) => {
        console.log('сейчас')
        setTimeout(() => console.log('позже'), 5000)
});
```

Если отправить на этот роут два запроса практически одновременно, то setTimeout отрабатывает только один раз: на выходе получаю

```
сейчас
сейчас
позже
```

Почему так? Как добиться поведения, когда на выходе будет

```
сейчас
сейчас
позже
позже
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась поднятием версии ноды до 17, описанное поведение было на 14 версии